# "com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: connection is closed by foreign host" when we are accessing the request using multiple threads(100 requests at a time)

Tags: multithreading, jsch

I am using jsch session(along with "exec" channel) to upload content from one server to another remote server, i have implemented scenarios and they are working fine for less number(5 to 10 threads) of requests at a time. If i hit for upload content service using 100 threads at a time i am getting the connection closed by foreign host exception. can anyone help me to resolve this?
I am using jersey client to access the tomcat requests.

Note: i am getting success for all the requests if i used to call the jersey client in "for loop" instead of using threads.

Client which i observed the exceptions for some requests(5 to 10 requests are failing for every 100 requests):

```
public class MultiThreadsExecution {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws ParseException, JSONException, IOException, InterruptedException {
        int i = 1;
        while (i <= 100) {
            Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    System.out.println("inside run method ");
                    int folderNo = new Random().nextInt(300);
                    String inputMetadata = "{'path':'/content/dam/en/us/products/collateral/arch/oct06/05'}";
                    String filePath = "C:\\Users\\sreenu\\Desktop\\testcontent\\documents\\testdoc.pdf";
                    // code goes here.
                    try {
                    //jersey client invoking
                        new JerseyPostClient().uploadContent(inputMetadata, filePath);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
            t1.start();
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Code snippet to get session: public com.jcraft.jsch.Session getSession(String host) throws LwpException,                    JSchException{
 JSch jsch = new JSch();
 com.jcraft.jsch.Session session = null;
 try {
  jsch.addIdentity(LwpConstants.PRIVATE_KEY);
  session = jsch.getSession(LwpConstants.XXWEM_USER, host , 22);
  session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
  session.connect();
 } catch (JSchException e) {
  LOGGER.error("Exception in getting the jsch session - :",e);
  throw new JSchException("Exception in getting session");
 }
 return session; 
}
}

Comment: The code in your question doesn't appear to contain any calls to Jsch, so it's hard to understand how it's relevant. The code that you added as a comment is virtually unreadable. You should [edit] your question to add that code to the question itself and explain how these pieces fit together.